# How to delete duplicates in the following example?

Tags: list-manipulation

COnsider a list

```
table = {{x1,y1,z1,t1},{x2,y2,z2,t2},...}
```

How to remove duplicates having the same values of {y,z} (say, {1,2,3,5},{99,2,3,9})? It is not important for me which exactly row will be remained.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`DeleteDuplicatesBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteDuplicatesBy.html)

```
DeleteDuplicatesBy[#[[{2, 3}]]&] @ table
```

Example:

```
table = RandomInteger[3, {7, 4}]
```

> {{1, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 3, 0}, {3, 0, 1, 
>         2}, {2, 3, 3, 0}, {3, 0, 1, 3}}

```
DeleteDuplicatesBy[#[[{2, 3}]] &] @table
```

> {{1, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 3, 0}, {2, 3, 3, 0}}

Alternatively, you can use `Union`:

```
Union[table, SameTest -> (#[[{2, 3}]] == #2[[{2, 3}]] &)]
```

> {{0, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 3, 0}, {2, 3, 3, 0}}

Note that `DeleteDuplicatesBy` keeps the elements that appear early in the original list while `Union` sorts the list.

Comment: Just to add: for large lists, `DeleteDuplicatesBy` is also significantly faster than using `Union` with `SameTest` since it does not have to run the test on each possible pair. If you want the output sorted, it's probably better to use `DeleteDuplicatesBy` and then `Sort`.